# Integrate Web Application with MS Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams

I have a web application created in ASP.NET, and I am looking if there is a way to integrate my application with Microsoft Teams.

What I am planning to achieve is the following:

After the user fills a form on my website, I would like to create a Teams meeting based on his selected date/duration from the form and inform him that the meeting is reserved for him based on the date that he picks.

Besides, I would like to know if it's possible to let the user join the meeting directly from my web application instead of sending him an email to join the meeting.

Is it possible to achieve the following scenario?

If yes, Can you please explain in detail and provide an example or documentation that can guide me to achieve my needs?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could try creating a Teams meeting using [Deeplinking to scheduling dialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links#linking-to-the-scheduling-dialog). This would take the details entered by the user from you web page and will navigate to a scheduling screen inside Teams. Regarding your question #2 Once a Teams meeting is scheduled, the user can directly click on Join meeting to join the meeting. It is not possible to allow the user to join a meeting within your web page.

Comment: Hello @Gousia-MSFT, thanks for your reply. Regarding the second question, even if i have tried to use Microsoft Graph API for Teams it's not possible to achieve this part? Looking forward to your response. Thanks again!

Comment: No. It is not possible to allow a user to join a Teams meeting from somewhere else.