# MS Teams app join with an existing ASP.NET Core web application

Tags: asp.net-core, microsoft-teams

I have an ASP.NET Core web app running on IIS. It's using ASP.NET Identity standard user/pass authentication and IdP initiated SSO for certain clients.

Now I need to get some of the web app features to MS Teams. I have gone through the MS Teams dev portal and have a test application up and running. The sample app itself is a Blazor app that we need to install as a separate application (let's say on an Azure app service or IIS).

Is it possible to have the Teams & my existing web application in the same project so that I don't have to create a separate site?

The reason is web app is multi-tenant enabled and have a API layer which anyway will have to be used by Teams app. So, if I can put these two together it may be easy? So in my solution, teams will have separate set of views/controls etc..

I am not sure whether my thought process is wrong in this case. Questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69027786/asp-net-web-forms-app-integrate-into-ms-teams)  and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60932736/integrate-web-application-with-ms-teams) doesn't seem to answer my requirement.

Anyway is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible you can run multiple projects in MS teams the difference would be that they will be having different api endpoints and will be called by different names vice versa. I cant get to know what you exactly want to know but I hope it will help you.